# Unable to read property values using config-client app from PCF config server service

Tags: spring-boot, gitlab, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry, pcf

> In my PCF logs config-client app gives
>   "ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource:
>   401 Unauthorized"

**I have gitlab repository to provide properties files in PCF config server.
If I check Config Server -> manage -> it gives "
Config server is online"**

Where am I missing the configuration?

bootstrap.yml  config-client-app

```
spring:
  application:
    name: <config-client-name>
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      name: <config-server-instance-name>
      uri: <uri details from view credential modal>
#      username: <tried different permutations to get it working>
#      password: <tried different permutations to get it working>
management: 
  security: 
    enabled: false
```

manifest.yml  config-client-app

```
applications:
- name: <app-name>
  host: <app-name>
  memory: 1024M
  instances: 1
  path: /target/<app-name>-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  buildpack: java_buildpack_offline
  services:
    - <pcf config server instance name>
  env:
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: dev
```

I have done lots of work around to get some result but no luck, sample app works fine.
I have tried my own config-server and config client app with github repository and it worked.

But in PCF I am totally stuck please help.

Comment: Have you contacted PCF support?

Comment: @spencergibb No, I haven't

Comment: a.) Try simplifying what you're doing. With SCS, you should be able to get away with just `spring.application.name` set in `boostrap.yml`. A lot is automated for you, so remove the rest for now and try to get a baseline working app. b.) Make sure you're following the instructions here -> https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/2-0/common/config-server/writing-client-applications.html and pulling in the appropriate SCS client dependencies. If you're unable to get that to work, start with the sample app which is working and gradually build on that. It'll help to identify what's not working

Comment: I understand that I may not need lots of details in ma ifest.yml. but, if I don't provide details then while app start on pcf it tries to find comfig server at localhost:8888

Comment: Are you using Pivotal's Spring Cloud Services (SCS) tile provided Config Server or are you providing your custom?

Comment: SCS, I guess. The one come with standard plan.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't a look anything wrong in your configuration. if you are seeing Config server is online in PCF that means config service is intialized properly and ready for use.

But let's try with the sample app which is working fine for you.

Add following information in you `build.gradle` if you are using gradle build(or add in `pom.xml` accordingly.)

1. [SCS(Spring Cloud services)](https://docs.run.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/client-dependencies.html#including-dependencies) (mentioned versions are compatible with `springBootVersion = '2.0.6.RELEASE'` Check for comparability if you are using a different version of spring-boot.)

   imports {

   ```
       mavenBom "io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-dependencies:2.0.1.RELEASE"
       mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.RELEASE"

    }
   ```
2. include config-client dependency

`compile("io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client")`

Now let's move to `bootstrap.yml`:
only following information is enough to pick the properties

```
spring:
  application:
    name: <config-client-name>
```

No change required in `application.yml` if you are using the same active profile while pushing to PCF.

Comment: Thanks, I could not get my gradle projects to import from the configuration server, (the maven projects worked just fine .. ). Your answer was the only one that worked ..

Answer (score 0):

@Avhi - your answer helped me.

My mistake was I was using wrong dependency, and I was adding unnecessary info. in **bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: <config-client-name>
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      name: <config-server-instance-name>
      uri: <uri details from view credential modal>
#      username: <tried different permutations to get it working> 
#      password: <tried different permutations to get it working>
management: 
  security: 
    enabled: false
```

`name: <config-server-instance-name>` we should configure the property file name that we are going to point from client application, I was providing config-server instance name.
Note: I have learnt that we can specify multiple properties files separated by comma.

```
uri: <uri details from view credential modal>
#      username: <tried different permutations to get it working> 
#      password: <tried different permutations to get it working>
```

The above three properties were useless and I wasted most of my time because of this.

We need not have these values set unless we want to bind config-server service in our localhost:8080 app.

There's no harm in providing service name in our manifest.yml and as it is not the part of application, it won't create any trouble. BTW we can use CLI or PCF App Manager web console to create and bind service to our app.

After setting up all, we can expect spring security web page to enter username & password (that obviously we don't know). if spring security is configured then fine or we can disable while testing.

I did two things to disable and activate all endpoints of actuator (as I am using spring-boot 2.x)

added dependencies as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId>
    <!-- <version>1.0.5.RELEASE</version> -->
</dependency>
```

and created SecurityConfiguration to disable security explicitly

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    }
}
```

To make all the actuators endpoints accessible I have done the following:

```
management: 
  endpoints: 
    web: 
      exposure: 
        include: "*"
```